# Finding the maximum value from the roots of a solution when there is an ambiguity

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a variable

```
x = l*Cos[t]*Cos[a] - Sin[t]*Sin[a]
```

and I want to find the maximum value of x with respect to a, as well as access the roots. I have tried
`MaxValue[x, a]` but but just get

```
MaxValue[l Cos[a] Cos[t]-Sin[a] Sin[t],a]
```

So I did `b = D[x, a]` and was returned

```
-l Cos[t] Sin[a]-Cos[a] Sin[t]
```

I then did `sx=Solve[b ==0, a]`
and was returned
[image: result of calculation]

so what I would like to do next is something like

```
mx =x/. a-> sx[[1]]
```

but I am not sure how to how to handle the `2 PI` ambiguity in the roots. Note that I want to extract the ambiguous roots even if it is possible to make `MaxValue` work. I just want the roots with c_1 = 0.

Comment: can you give more info like Domains or helping info about your problem

Comment: it shows that C1 is complex, what about domain of other values !? any extra info!?

Comment: c_1 is in Z, and in this case, Z is just the integers, i.e. not complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Weierstrass-Subsitution`:  `a->2 ArcTan[u] && u->Tan[a/2]` which restricts `a` to the range `-Pi<a<Pi` and transforms the equation to a rational form.

```
x = l*Cos[t]*Cos[a] - Sin[t]*Sin[a]
xu = x /. a -> 2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand
(*(l Cos[t])/(1 + u^2) - (l u^2 Cos[t])/(1 + u^2) - (2 u Sin[t])/(1 + u^2)*)
```

Now `MaxValue` evaluates maximum of `x`

```
max=MaxValue[xu, u] /. u -> Tan[a/2]
(*-Sqrt[l^2 Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2]*)
```

`ArgMax` evaluates for which argument  `u` the maximum is found

```
maxu = ArgMax[xu, u]
(*-(Sin[t]/(l Cos[t] + Sqrt[l^2 Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2])) ...*)
```

All valid solutions `a` follow to `a==2 ArcTan[maxu]+2 Pi Integer`

Comment: I like this, it is elegant.  However, as mentioned in the question, I also want to know the value of the roots, i.e of a. How do I do this?

Comment: Now my answer includes the value of the roots...

Comment: Thank you, I have upvoted and accepted your answer. If you think the question may be of use to others, then please upvote it.  I suggest we delete our comments as all the information needed is now in the answer.